# Retrofit2(синхронная и асинхронная работа)

Tags: android, retrofit

Нужен совет, есть 3 асинхронных потока:

Поток первый(1) который стартует он получает количество новостей на сайте и отрабатывает лишь один раз

Поток второй(2) который получает само содержимое поста(id, content...id_img)

Поток третий(3) который получает изображение поста(которому нужен id_img из (2) потока)

Как передать id_img из (2) потока в (3) поток?

Получение общего количества постов:

```
final int[] size = new int[1];
    Call<ArrayList<PostModel>> call0 = api.getPost(100);//Тут получаем колличество постов
    call0.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<PostModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<PostModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<PostModel>> response) {
             size[0] = response.body().size();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<PostModel>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Тут получаем сами посты

```
Call<ArrayList<PostModel>> call = api.getPost(size[0]); //Получаем все посты(ID Изображения получаем тут же)
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<PostModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<PostModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<PostModel>> response) {
            ArrayList<PostModel> post = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<PostModel>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error load content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

И тут получаем изображение по ID

```
Call<ArrayList<ImageModel>> call1 = api.getImage(504);//Тут ID изображения
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<ImageModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<ImageModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<ImageModel>> response) {
            ArrayList<ImageModel> img = response.body();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<ImageModel>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

P.S.

```
Call<ArrayList<ImageModel>> call1 = api.getImage(504)
```

Вместо 504 должен быть id который мы получаем вместе с содержимым поста в (2) потоке

Comment: А где собственно потоки? Весь код что тут написан (колбэки), будет отрабатываться в том же потоке, в котором создан (UI скорее всего).

Comment: retrofit сам создает для себя потоки(если идет асинхронная работа), для синхронной работы только нужно создавать отдельно потоки

Comment: Вам не надо вообще думать что там и как создает retrofit в случае асинхронных вызовов. Потому что вот из документации: `On Android, callbacks will be executed on the main thread. On the JVM, callbacks will happen on the same thread that executed the HTTP request.`

Comment: Обработка callback происходит в главном потоке, отправка запроса происходит в фоновом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, написал вот такой код:

Переменная j объявлена как глобальная и используется для счетчика(небольшой костыль),да возможно и сам код написан не правильно но,работает.

Может кому-то тоже поможет

P.S. Тут же идет работа с БД(Sugar ORM)

```
Call<ArrayList<PostModel>> call = api.getPost(100);//Тут получаем все посты
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<PostModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<PostModel>> call, final Response<ArrayList<PostModel>> response) {
            postORM = new ArrayList<>();
            size = response.body().size();
            for(int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) { // Узнаем колличество постов
                postORM.add(new PostModelORM( //Добавляем посты в Базу данных
                        Integer.parseInt(response.body().get(i).getIdPost()),
                        response.body().get(i).getGuid().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getDate(),
                        response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getContent().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered(),
                        response.body().get(i).getCategroiesMass()));
                SugarRecord.saveInTx(postORM);//Сохраняет пост в БД
                Call<ArrayList<ImageModel>> call1 = api.getImage(Integer.parseInt(response.body().get(i).getIdPost())); //Получаем  изображение по ID поста
                call1.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<ImageModel>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<ImageModel>> call1, Response<ArrayList<ImageModel>> response1) {
                        if(response1.body().size()  == 1) { //Получаем одно изображение
                                postORM.get(j).setUrl_img(response1.body().get(0).getGuid().getRendered());

                        }else if(response1.body().size() == 0) { //Нет изображений
                                postORM.get(j).setUrl_img("");

                        }else{
                            for(int i = 0; i < response1.body().size(); i++) { //Получаем несколько изображений
                                postORM.get(j).setUrl_img(response.body().get(i).getGuid().getRendered() + " ");

                            }
                        }
                        j++;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<ImageModel>> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<PostModel>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Весь ваш вопрос сводится по сути к простой задаче как реализовать такой паттерн

```
void a() {
  int result = // some calculation
  b(result);
}
void b(int resultFromA) {
  int resut = 2 * resultFromA;
  c(result);
}
void c(int resultFromB) {
  // do something with resultFromB value
}
```

Потоки тут совсем лишние.

Comment: Работа с сетью без потоков? Насколько я знаю, для работы с сетью необходимо выделять отдельный фоновый поток чтобы он не грузил UI , возможно я не прав?

Comment: Потоками занимается ретрофит, в этом и фишка его асинхронных запросов. Вам могут понадобиться свои потоки если какие-то еще операции с данными, кроме сетевых, могут занимать время.